# Code on Heroku deployed, but not installed Dependencies

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I tried to deploy my Discord JS App to Heroku. When deployed, it seems that node already installed all the dependencies. But on application logs, it missing there.

Here's my latest build log

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.16.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.9.0

       Resolving node version 10.16.3...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
       npm 6.9.0 already installed with node

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules (not cached - skipping)

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       up to date in 0.303s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules (nothing to cache)

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       up to date in 0.282s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 19.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v15
       https://botcia-discordjs.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I think the deployment doesn't seem to have any issue. But then I have an error from application log so the bot can't start.

```
2020-01-22T06:47:36.137591+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-01-22T06:47:37.772565+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2020-01-22T06:47:38.336892+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-22T06:47:39.738190+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-01-22T06:47:39.721156+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-01-22T06:47:39.657493+00:00 app[worker.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2020-01-22T06:47:39.657520+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2020-01-22T06:47:39.657522+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2020-01-22T06:47:39.657523+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2020-01-22T06:47:39.657525+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
//more error
```

Actually the first error found is cannot find module thing. So if I managed to fix discord.js, I'll get another issue.
My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "1",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "youtube-info": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx"
  },
  "author": "XXXX <xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
  "private": false
}
```

`Procfile` file:

```
worker: node main.js
```

`requirements.txt` file:

```
npm install discord.js
```

Please take a note that I deploy the server using GUI on its website and not CLI. So I don't know how to solve it without CLI.

Comment: You're not uploading the `node_modules` folder as well by chance? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#how-to-keep-build-artifacts-out-of-git

Comment: Is it a test project? Could you let me know git link to that project?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to deploy the application and then, at the CLI, write `npm install`. It will install all the packages defined at package.json.